# BiometricManager.canAuthenticate() = BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS but BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() returns errorCode 9 on lockout

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

Just as the title says, my project is using `BiometricManager.from(context).canAuthenticate()` to determine if a user is eligible to be prompted for Biometrics, then using `BiometricPrompt` to actually save/access the password.

Once Biometrics are successfully setup and I force 5 incorrect fingerprint scans locking the user out, the next time the user tries to authenticate I am getting a "success" value from `canAuthenticate()` but when `BiometricPrompt` is called the `onAuthenticationError()` callback is being triggered with errorCode 9. This is leaving the user in limbo of always having biometrics "enabled" but not being able to use them. Is there any known way to check lockout before calling BiometricPrompt?

[canAuthenticate() success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iCt8.png)

[BiometricPrompt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dx2R.png)